# How to vertically stack panels of sjPlot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I got a meaningful four-way interaction to plot using `sjPlot` in R, here is an example:

```
colnames(iris) <- c("y", "a", "b", "c", "d")

m0 <- lm(y ~ a * b * c * d, data = iris)

sjPlot::plot_model(m0, type = "pred", terms = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Which plots:
[image]
I want to stack them vertically by `d`.

`sjpPlot` is `ggplot2` based, but it does not simply take `ggplot` commends. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the image of your plot (which is already a multi-panel figure) I would guess that you have installed the `see` package, i.e. if not you will get a list of single plots and the warning:

> Package `see` needed to plot multiple panels in one integrated figure.
> Please install it by typing `install.packages("see", dependencies = TRUE)` into the console.

will pop up.

If `see` is installed `sjPlot::plot_model` will return a multi-panel plot which uses `patchwork` under the hood, i.e. the returned object is no longer a list of `ggplot`s but a `patchwork` object instead. (As a consequence applying `patchwork::wrap_plots` as suggested in the (now deleted) answer by @jared_mamrot will not have any effect.)

Instead, for this case you could set the number of columns via `patchwork::plot_layout`.

Note: My guess is that there is or should be an argument to control which type of object is returned or the number of columns in case of multi-panel plots. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find something on that in the documentation. (:

```
library(patchwork)
require(see)

p <- sjPlot::plot_model(m0, type = "pred", terms = c("a", "b", "c", "d")) 

p +
  plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: @jared_mamrot IMHO you could still undelete your answer as it provides a solution for the non-"see" case. To make it more "complete" I would probably add some more tweaks like getting rid of the duplicated titles and collecting the guides. Overall personally I would prefer having the option to get a list of plots which I can tweak more easily than manipulating a patchwork object.

Answer (score 2):

I think @stefan's answer is the best solution to the problem, however, if you don't have the "see" package installed (the function warns you if this is the case), `plot_model()` generates a list of plots instead of a single figure. A potential solution for this scenario is to use the patchwork library, which accepts a list of plots as input, e.g.

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

colnames(iris) <- c("y", "a", "b", "c", "d")
  
m0 <- lm(y ~ a * b * c * d, data = iris)
  
list_of_plots <- plot_model(m0, type = "pred", terms = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
#> Warning: Package `see` needed to plot multiple panels in one integrated figure.
#>   Please install it by typing `install.packages("see", dependencies =
#>   TRUE)` into the console.

# You can edit the plots to suit, e.g. remove titles from plots 2 and 3
list_of_plots[[2]] <- list_of_plots[[2]] + labs(title = "")
list_of_plots[[3]] <- list_of_plots[[3]] + labs(title = "")

wrap_plots(list_of_plots, ncol = 1, guides = "collect")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>